# On click next TD/div

Tags: class, click, html-table

I have a script that on click changes the class style but after he does that I want him to change the next TD or DIV style as well.

```
$('.can-select').click(function(e){
    $(this).addClass("is-selected");
    $(this).children('.can-select-text').addClass("is-selected");

});
```

can-select is a div and a image class that are clickable.
can-select-text its a div for text

next td or div is class is "nothing".

Comment: Is `.can-select-text` class elements(div) within `.can-select` class ?

Comment: Yes. That part is working. The problem is finding the next class with name nothing :\

Comment: you want to search for the class `.nothing` and add class `.is-selected` to it ?

Comment: if yes, then try this  `$('.nothing').addClass("is-selected");`.

Comment: that will change all nothing class. I want to change the next one after that one that was pressed before.

Comment: `$(this).next('.nothing').addClass("is-selected");` . this should be work for you then

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/ its not working :\

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/1/ . here is the updated fiddle, there were certain loop holes , i have fixed it :)

Comment: why doesnt the second circle show then? :x

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/2/. is this fine now ?

Comment: I dont understand how doesnt it work this way: http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/3/ If we set incial opacity to 0 and then we add a class with opacity 1. shouldnt it appear?

Comment: oh we have to remove the class before adding other... it stays: "nothing is-selected"

Comment: yep. we need to remove the class which is setting opacity as zero and set a class with opacity 1. cant have both css setting. it will corrupt.

Comment: I'm not getting it right but I'll try a bit later. I'm not being able to remove because he move to next one after I do it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/4/. hey buddy i understood the error, u were talking abt, i have updated the fiddle. let me know if u still have problem

Comment: Thanks a lot :D it was something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/5/ Now I have to make the second circle repeate what the other did.

Comment: If you need to repeat this process further with other td`s , then u need to use a specific id for td. because class identifies a group whereas id represent unique element. thats the reason "id" selector was created. i guess you got the logic on the whole. you can repeat the same when using id for td`s. since u found the answer for this question, i`ll post the code in answer section, u can tick it as answer, to close the question from open questions pool :)

Comment: I will make it but I'm just confused with one thing. If that td i going to be can-select1 and there is no more with that value since it was changed on that click, why doesnt it work again?

Comment: thats beacause it has already added the class ".is-selected" to its child elements.it you want it to work again u gotta remove it  and add it again.lets do one thing, you go ahead create a new SO question with the requirement what u want and let me know . will have a look at it.

Comment: did that, I think this way is better using the ids like you said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383031/on-div-click-show-all-divs-with-x-id

Comment: Yep , thats how it should be done . Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the fiddle defined as per your requirement.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/5/)

**JS CODE**

```
$('.can-select1').click(function (e) {
    $(this).addClass("is-selected");
    $(this).find('.can-select').addClass("is-selected");
    $(this).children('.can-select-text').addClass("is-selected");
    var nextTd;
    nextTd = $(this).parent().find('.nothing1');
    nextTd.find('.nothing').addClass("can-select1");
    nextTd.addClass("can-select1");
    nextTd.removeClass('nothing1')

});
```