# on div click show all divs with X id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I want that when I click on one of the circle it shows the next row of circles. But can only have on with is-selected class. This is the code I have:

```
<table>
<tr>           
<td>
                        <div style="position: relative;" class="can-select1">
                            <img src="http://lkimg.zamimg.com/images/guides/ability-marker.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="can-select">
                            <div class="can-select-text">1</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style="position: relative;" class="nothing1" id="tier1">
                            <img src="http://lkimg.zamimg.com/images/guides/ability-marker.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="nothing">
                            <div class="can-select-text">2</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>           
<td>
                        <div style="position: relative;" class="can-select1">
                            <img src="http://lkimg.zamimg.com/images/guides/ability-marker.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="can-select">
                            <div class="can-select-text">1</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style="position: relative;" class="nothing1" id="tier1">
                            <img src="http://lkimg.zamimg.com/images/guides/ability-marker.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="nothing">
                            <div class="can-select-text">2</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.can-select1').click(function(e){
    $(this).addClass("is-selected");
    $(this).find('.can-select').addClass("is-selected");
    $(this).children('.can-select-text').addClass("is-selected");
});
```

CSS:

```
.can-select1 {
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0.4;
}
.can-select-text{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 32px;
    font: bold 13px/32px 'Trebuchet Ms';
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); color: #111;
}
.is-selected {
    cursor:default;
    opacity:1.0;
}

.nothing1{
    cursor:default;
    opacity:0;
}
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/7/

Comment: `id`'s must be unique, use classes intead

Comment: In what way is what you have not working?  We're happy to help, but just posting code and telling us what you want doesn't really show any effort.  Can you describe the problem?

Comment: I've tried everything already, im only being able to do this next TD by next TD, and what I need is that 1 click changes class in the 2 other buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you actually want but this should help:

http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/8/

First, `id`s must be unique. I removed them.

Next, I added the line:

```
$(this).closest('td').next('td').find('.nothing1').removeClass('nothing1').addClass('can-select1');
```

This traverses from the button, up to the parent `td`, to the next sibling `td`, looks for its `.nothing1` button, and makes it clickable.

Also, I changed the `click` handler line to:

```
$('table').on('click','.can-select1',function(e){
```

So the handler will apply when classes are added and removed. As you had it, the handler will only apply to the elements that existed when the page loaded for the first time.

---

**edit**

To modify all next `td` in the column:

```
$(this).closest('td').nextAll('td').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.nothing1').removeClass('nothing1').addClass('can-select1');
});
```

---

**edit** after chat, here's a re-write

http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/12

Use radio buttons and labels:

```
<td class="column-0 selectable">
    <input type="radio" name="column-0" id="column-0-row-0">
    <label for="column-0-row-0">
        <img src="http://lkimg.zamimg.com/images/guides/ability-marker.png">
        <div>1</div>
    </label>
</td>
```

Do all the styling in css without names:

```
td input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
td input[type="radio"] + label {
    display:none;
    cursor:default;
    opacity:0;
    position: relative;
}
td input[type="radio"] + label img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td input[type="radio"] + label div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 32px;
    font: bold 13px/32px'Trebuchet Ms';
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: #111;
}

td.selectable input[type="radio"] + label {
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0.4;
}
td.selectable input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved 1 problem, what I cant do is make 1 button from left side change class on the 2 buttons on the right side. instead of 1 by 1 with next TD.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Sorry I was typing from phone. Basicly what I was looking for was a way that one button from the left (1´s) could change the one's from the right. ATM only one button changes the next one, but I want to change the whole column.

Comment: I couldnt make that work.

Comment: I don't think you're showing your entire html in the question.

Comment: I am, all I have its on the jsfiddle. At least about this issue it is. But I will replicate more buttons as soon as I figure out how to solve that issue :\ Edit: I see what you understand, I dont need only to modify next TD's. I want that when I press one button in the column ( each TR) that he shows next TD and the one that was below (in the other TR)

Comment: Ah, a game of Lights Out! http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)

Comment: Its almost this: http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/9/ But without showing the last td I've added to test.

Comment: Its almost that, but Instead of just showing the next two rectangles, I want to show all the next in the next column. from the perpective I've made.

Comment: Would you describe this as a "Rook's Move"? Sorry for all the clarification. Maybe a drawing would be better

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32641/discussion-between-joe-frambach-and-cristiano-marques)

Comment: Here is a fiddle with rook's moves: http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/10/

Comment: I'm just playing around with it